# How to create table based on minimum date from other table in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to create a second table from the first table using filters with dates and other variables as follows. How can I create this?

Following is the expected table and original table,

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a visual or do you need to write a new calculated table for some reason?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to create different table as i want to utilize this for other operations.

Comment: I have answered your post, Is that matching your query?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Edit Queries`. Lets say our base table is named `RawData`. Add a blank query and use this expression to copy your `RawData` table:

```
=RawData
```

[image]

The new table will be `RawDataGrouped`. Now select the new table and go to `Home > Group By` and use the following settings:

[image]

The result will be the following table. Note that I didnt use the exactly values you used to keep this sample at a miminum effort:

[image]

You also can now create a relationship between this two tables (by the `Index` column) to use cross filtering between them.

You could show the grouped data and use the relationship to display the `RawDate` in a subreport (or custom tooltip) for example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and solution. Actually, I am looking for DAX syntax because minimum date selection will be dynamic and if i use date slicer then I can not reverse communicate with Query Editor.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for a calculated table. Below is the workaround for the same,

In **Query Editor** you can create a duplicate table of the existing (Original) table and select the ***Date Filter -> Is Earliest*** option by clicking right corner of the Date column in new duplicate table. Now your table should contain only the rows which are having minimum date for the column.

Note: This table is dynamic and will give subsequent results based on data changes in the original table, but you to have refresh both the table.

[image]

**Original Table:**

[image]

**Desired Table:**

[image]

When I have added new column into it, post to refreshing dataset I have got below result (This implies, it is doing recalculation based on each data change in the original source)

**New data entry:**

[image]

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply and solution. Actually, I am looking for DAX syntax.

Comment: This will work for your need, if you have any changes in date or any new data have been added into the original table then this table will do recalculation.

Comment: Okay. If i change the data from Power BI Desktop slicer how it will filter the data in the Query Editor?

Comment: Please be clear with your requirement, If you need DAX then it's a measure. You can't have a dynamic table based on slicer selection which is not possible.

Comment: As per your question, you want table which is filter with date of minimum value. Which is answered. Current question is different from what you are asking now.. You can feel free to raise another question.

Comment: I have already mentioned in the question. Thanks for your help. "How to create table based on minimum date from other table in DAX?"

Comment: That question is been answered, but your current req is to create table based on date slicer selection from visual. which is not possible in Power BI calculated table.